# NGINX configuration for Django static files and Vue.js statics directory

Tags: django, nginx, quasar-framework

I have an NGINX configuration for a containerized Django application that does three things:

1. routes traffic to a container running daphne (on `/api/`, `/admin/` and `/ws/` routes)
2. serves Django static files
3. serves static files for a Vue.js application that uses Quasar

My Vue.js application includes a few small images that should be served on `/statics/` (with an `s`), and my Django static files are served on `/static/`. I can either have the `/statics/` images from Vue.js working, or the `/static/` files from Django working, but no both. Here's the configuration that makes Django static files work but Vue.js `/statics/` files fail to load:

```
    # static files
    location /static {
      autoindex on;
      alias /usr/src/app/assets/static;
    }
```

If I change the above to `location /static/ {`, then the Vue.js statics images will work but the Django static files will fail to load.

Here's my full NGINX configuration file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  upstream backend {
    server backend:9000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;

    root /dist/;
    index index.html;

    # frontend
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    }

    location @rewrites {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

    # static files
    location /static {
      autoindex on;
      alias /usr/src/app/assets/static;
    }

    # backend urls
    location ~ ^/(admin|api|ws) {
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to keep the route names `/static/` and `/statics/` in the NGINX configuration the same, I probably need to change the Django `/static` block.

I'm now trying to change the options described here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this working correctly now, I had to add a `/` to the end of the alias path:

```
    # static files
    location /static {
      autoindex on;
      alias /usr/src/app/assets/static/;
    }
```